# How to write in-class function from non-class function c++?

Tags: c++, member-functions, non-member-functions

I have merge function which is a non-class.

Merge.cpp

```
template <typename T>
vector<T> merge(vector<T> left, vector<T> right){
    vector<T> result;
    int left_current = 0, right_current = 0;
    while(left_current < left.size() && right_current < right.size()){
        if(left[left_current] <= right[right_current]){
            result.push_back(left[left_current]); 
            left_current++;
        }else{
            result.push_back(right[right_current]); 
            right_current++;
        }
    }
    while(left_current < left.size()){
        result.push_back(left[left_current]); 
        left_current++; 
    }
    while(right_current < right.size()){
        result.push_back(right[right_current]); 
        right_current++;    
    }
    return result;
}


template <typename T>
vector<T> merge_sort(vector<T> arr){
    vector<T> left, right, result;
    if(arr.size() <= 1)
        return arr;
    int middle = arr.size() / 2;

    for(int i=0;i<middle;i++){
        left.push_back(arr[i]);
    }
    for(int i=middle;i<arr.size();i++){
        right.push_back(arr[i]);
    }

    left = merge_sort(left);
    right = merge_sort(right);
    arr = merge(left,right);
    return arr;
}
```

Normally, I am calling merge in main like this way.

```
vector<int> sorted_vector=merge_sort(my_vector);
```

But, I want to call in main like this way.

```
my_vector.merge_sort()
```

For calling in second way, I taught I need a member function which takes no parameters and arguments of Sorter class. So, I implemented my member function like following.

Sorter.cpp

```
template<typename T>
void Sorter<T>::merge_sort(){

    vector<int> sorted_vector = merge_sort(my_vector_2);

}
```

I made a research and I found this is about helper functions but I could not figure it out.Is my approach is correct ?

Comment: `my_vector` is a `std::vector<int>` ? You cannot add members to classes on the fly like that. Whats wrong with a free function?

Comment: its not clear why you think having a member would be better than free function. I suggest you to read this: https://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197 Actually if possible free functions are prefered over members

Comment: You can't.   `std::vector` is a templated type in the standard library, and it's not possible in C++ to add member functions to standard types.    It is only possible to add member functions to your *own* `struct` or `class` types, where you have control over (i.e. can edit) the `struct` or `class` definition.    And that has to be done in the whole program (having two different definitions in different source files gives undefined behaviour, except in specialised cases that differ from what you seek).  Although `std::vector` is a templated class, you don't have such control.

Comment: I have been asked to write a member function as an assignment which takes no parameters and return values. Since the merge sort is a recursive function, I taught that I can call actual function that does the sorting job from the member function

Comment: oh, certainly you can call a free function from a member function

Comment: I see that you've got a class called `Sorter<T>` - what is it? is it a vector-like thing that needs to be sorted?

Comment: Sorter class has methods like insert, insertion_sort, get_size, print etc. Yes it has also vector that needs to be sorted.

Comment: Alright, then if that's true, then you are going in a good direction, but in `Sorter<T>::merge_sort`  doing `vector<int> sorted_vector = merge_sort(my_vector_2);` you have to ensure that `my_vector_2` contains data from the Sorter object, and later the returned `sorted vector` is what you wanted to get, but it's not yet written back to the Sorter object, so you need to take care of it too!

Comment: I created my_vector_2  in the main also.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl the second is from "teach" not "learn"

Comment: `I created my_vector_2 in the main also.` then it will not work. `main()` is another scope. The member function `Sorter<T>::merge_sort` will not see `my_vector_2` variable. Since Sorter<T> is a vector-like thing, or contains a vector with data, be sure to pass that data or that vector to the sorting function.

Comment: @idclev463035818: yeah true, thanks, I wrote it with google-translate and it did not feel OK, but somehow I didn't re-check it. Comment removed. I have to be MOAR careful. Funny thing: I have the same teach-learn problem when learning japanese.. oshieru?manabu? I still don't remember which is which :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm going to spout some platitudes.

- Functions that are pure -- that take explicit input and return explicit output -- are easier to reason about.
- Be lazy, do less work.

Methods are, in general, impure; they operate on the object they are attached to, taking and returning its entire state implicitly.  So if the function itself isn't a mess, state-wise, try to keep it as a pure function.

On the other hand, having a function attached to an object is nice for the purpose of code-completion; by mentioning the noun (the object) first, brainless code-completion code can find your method and its signature easier.  Meanwhile, free functions are this huge pile of verbs that is harder for code-completion tools to work with.

---

Next, this code has a small issue you'll want to clean up:

```
template <typename T>
vector<T> merge(vector<T> left, vector<T> right){
```

tweak this to:

```
template <typename T>
vector<T> merge(vector<T> const& left, vector<T> const& right){
```

or even better, get ahold of `span` objects for `left`/`right`.

---

For your method:

```
template<typename T>
void Sorter<T>::merge_sort();
```

now, other than as an exercise, having a stateful object that is a "Sorter" is pretty ridiculous.

I assume it looks something like this:

```
template<typename T>
class Sorter {
public:
  std::vector<T> m_data;
  void merge_sort();
};
```

(the `m_` part is just a reminder that this is a member).

In this case, you'd write `merge_sort` like this:

```
template<typename T>
void Sorter::merge_sort() {
  m_data = ::merge_sort(m_data);
}
```

and done.

(if `merge_sort` is in a namespace, say `my_code`, replace `::` with `my_code::`).

The annoying part is that `merge_sort` the method and `merge_sort` the function have the same name.  By default, the member blocks finding the function, because of name lookup rules.  The `::` or `my_code::` tells the compiler which `merge_sort` you are talking about.